# Snowflake Response Json Has Whitespace?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here is a simple snowflake query that selects an object:

```
sf = connection.cursor()

sf.execute(f"""
SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('foo', 'bar')
""")

for row in sf.fetchall():
    yield row
```

When I run this, the response appears to be:

```
['{\n"foo": "bar"\n}']
```

With whitespace chars and all. Ideally it would just come back as a dict, but if that's not possible could it come back without whitespace?

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake formats JSON with line breaks and indents. This will make it come back without line breaks, indents, or spaces:

```
   sf.execute(f"""
SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('foo', 'bar')::string
""")
```